# LiveCD Boot Failer comm: Swapper/0 cant mount VFS

Tags: boot, kernel

Kind of a noob but anyway...

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 12.10 livecd. I currently have Windows 7 x64 installed. I start computer to boot Ubuntu livecd and I get kernel panic. Something like:
cannot mount VFS to (0,0)
comm swapper/0 not tainted

or something like that. I have no idea what to do!

Comment: either you have a corrupted cd, or aren't actually booting from the cd.